# Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:55408/ShopProcessService.svc

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting the following error when trying to launch the WCF Test client for a service and is driving me crazy. I have searched the web and sounds like the DataContract Name of `HeaderRecord` exists twice in my project.

However, as doing a "find all" on this name only turned up one instance.

**Can somebody please help me with this error.** I'm at my wits end...

```
DataContract for type 'Ryder.Enterprise.DataTransferObjects.HeaderRecord[]' cannot be added to DataContractSet since type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Ryder.Enterprise.DataTransferObjects.HeaderRecord, Ryder.Enterprise.DataTransferObjects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with the same data contract name 'ArrayOfHeaderRecord' in namespace 'http://www.ABC.com/SOA/DataContracts/2014/02/17' is already present and the contracts are not equivalent.
```

There is also no instance in my project of a name called `ArrayOfHeaderRecord`.

### EDIT 1

Just for giggles, I decided to remove the Operation and Service Contract for this particular call into the method, and the WCF Test client came up successfully. When I put the contracts back in, that's when I get the error, but I still don't know why???

I even went back to an old version of my source code for this method (when it was coming up in the WCF Test client) and that failed as well.

I rebooted my machine and same thing is occurring. I don't understand this error. Even if I put back the contracts and just have a "shell" of my class that it's calling, I get the same error.

I don't know what to do anymore???

### EDIT 2 - Resolution

After tracing down everything in my solution, I found what the error was...
My class was listed as follows: Notice the implementing of the List object which should not be there.

```
public class HeaderRecordCollection : List<HeaderRecord>
    {
        private List<HeaderRecord> headerRecords;



        public HeaderRecordCollection()
        {
        }


        [DataMember(Name = "HeaderRecords")]
        public List<HeaderRecord> HeaderRecords
        {
            get
            {
                return headerRecords;
            }
            set
            {
                headerRecords = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I simply removed that where I only have one list. Since now only having one list for the object, no complaints from WCF!

Comment: Can you show the declaration for `HeaderRecord` and where you have a reference to an array of `HeaderRecord` objects in your data contracts?

Comment: See EDIT 1 in my post.

Comment: Thanks, but I still think seeing your code would be helpful. `ArrayOfHeaderRecord` just means an array of type `HeaderRecord`.

Comment: See my resolution in Edit 2.

Answer (score 1):

Two years late, but hey ;)

Substitute Attribute DataContract for CollectionDataContract